# Answer yes on powershell opening prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have the next powershell line of code

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{ start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file D:\powershell\mastermove2.ps1' -verb RunAs}"
```

The idea of the code is to execute the mastermove2.ps1 file as an administrator, the problem I'm having right now is when I execute this code from the command line I get the next powershell prompt

PowerShell prompt :

[image]

How do I automaticaly press yes on this prompt so that way mastermove2.ps1 executes without the user interaction?

Comment: If you can automatically press yes, then so can a virus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to elevate your process and give it administrator permissions.
Windows [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)
is protecting your safety and asking for permission to do so.
It's extremely recommended not to disable UAC, as it protects you from
permission-escalation attacks by viruses.

If you wish to avoid this prompt, you may create in PowerShell the
administrator credentials and attach them to the new process.
This will require including the administrator password in your script,
and many people will be horrified by the idea.

I'm including the following example code which answers the question,
but I do not recommend this method, unless you feel that your
environment is very secure and nobody can sneak a look at your
script.

```
$uid = "userid"
$pw = "password"
$secPw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pw -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $uid, $secPw
Start-Process powershell -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Minimized -ArgumentList "-noexit -command Start-Process cmd -verb runas"
```

Comment: this gave me an idea, what I did was create a scheduled task executing the powershell file with the admin user, that way the password won't be in plain sight

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't. Regular (non-elevated) programs are not allowed to interact with the UAC prompt, and that is the whole point of the "Run as administrator" UAC prompt and of UAC in general.

If this is something you need to do often – define a custom task via Task Scheduler which runs under your account with "all privileges".